# Spam message requests in Signal, how to block them?

Tags: signal

Over the last couple of weeks, I have started receiving obvious spam/fishing message requests in Signal on my iPhone from random phone numbers.

I have looked through the app settings and on the web site, but can't see any sort of option to block this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's on my iPhone.

Comment: If the app doesn’t support it, what you you expect as answers? To raise a feature request, contacting Signal directly is the better approach.

Comment: I don't know that it doesn't *support* it, or if I simply cannot *find* it. That is what I am asking.

Comment: Editing this to differentiate it from a basic customer support question will help people decide to cast reopen votes